# tr Id in JqGrid always 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I wrote a table with JqGrid, but I found every row`s property of table is "tr id = 0" Following is my code and screenshot. What caused this error? Any help will be appreciated.

```js
jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid({
        datatype: "json",
        url:"getAllUserInfo.do",
        mtype: 'POST',
        height: 250,
        colNames: ['Operation', 'userID', 'UserName', 'FullName', 'Department', 'Role', 'Telephone', 'MobilePhone', 'Mail', 'Status'],

        colModel: [
            {name: 'myac', index: '', width: 80, fixed: true, sortable: false, resize: false,search:false,
                formatter: 'actions',
                formatoptions: {
                    keys: true,
                    delOptions: {recreateForm: true, beforeShowForm: beforeDeleteCallback},
                    onSuccess:function(respone){
                        var msg=respone.responseText;
                        if(msg=='success')
                            return true;
                        else
                          {
                          alert(msg);
                             return [false,msg];
                            }
                        },
                     editOptions:{recreateForm: true, beforeShowForm:beforeEditCallback,}
                }
            },
         
         {name: 'userID', index: 'userID', width: 60, sorttype: "int", editable:false, sortable:false, search:false, align:'center' },
            {name: 'userName', index: 'userName', width: 100, editable: true, sorttype: "text",searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','in','ni']},editrules:{required:true},align:'center'},
            {name: 'fullName', index: 'fullName', width: 100, editable: true, sorttype: "text", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','in','ni']},editoptions: {size: "20", maxlength: "30"}},
            {name: 'department', index: 'department', width: 100, editable: true, sorttype: "text", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','in','ni']},editoptions: {size: "20", maxlength: "30"},editrules:{required:true}},
            {name: 'role', index: 'role', width: 70, editable: true, sorttype: "text",searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','in','ni']}, editrules:{required:true}},
            {name: 'telephone', index: 'telephone', width: 70, editable: true, sorttype: "text", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','in','ni']},editrules:{required:true,number:true}},
            {name: 'mobilePhone', index: 'mobilePhone', width: 150,editable:true, edittype:"text", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','in','ni']}},
            {name: 'mail', index: 'mail', width: 150,editable:true, edittype:"text", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','in','ni']}},
            {name: 'status', index: 'status', width: 60, editable:true, edittype:"text", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne']}}
            
        ],
        viewrecords: true,
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        pager: pager_selector,
        altRows: true,
        multiselect: true,
        multiboxonly: true,
        onCellSelect:function(rowid, e){        
           
            },
        gridComplete:function (){
         $("#grid-table").closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view")
                 .children("div.ui-jqgrid-titlebar")
                .css("text-align", "center").css("line-height","40px")
                 .children("span.ui-jqgrid-title")
                  .css("float", "none");
        },
        loadComplete: function () {
            var table = this;
            setTimeout(function () {
                var msg= $("#grid-table").getGridParam('userData');
          
                styleCheckbox(table);
                updateActionIcons(table);
                updatePagerIcons(table);
                enableTooltips(table);
            }, 0);
            var re_records = $("#grid-table").getGridParam('records');
         if(re_records == 0 || re_records == null){
          if($(".norecords").html() == null){
           $("#grid-table").parent().append("<div class=\"norecords\">No Records</div>");
          }
          $(".norecords").show();
         }
         else
             {
          $(".norecords").hide();
             }
        },
        editurl:"userInfoOperate.do",
        caption: "UserList",
        autowidth: true,
       
    });
```

[image: Img]

Comment: Which data returns `getAllUserInfo.do`? The values for id come typically from the server. You can use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or Network tab of Developer Tools of IE/Chrome to see HTTP traffic and to find out which data exactly returns your server. Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)?

Comment: Thanks, it is a server problem. I didn`t get a valid json string from server. I have solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Check it whether rows data has column with "id" as the name, just like the picture shows below. JqGrid will use the value of "id" column in rows data as the id value of tr tags, if it does have an id column in rows data.
[image: picture]

Comment: Thank you.  It is a server problem. I didn`t get a valid json string from server. I have solved it. But your point of view is also important.